# Linebreaks django y html

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código en un template de django

```
<div style="background-color:#F1948A;padding:0;border-radius:5px;margin:2;">
        <p style="margin-left:10;">{{ post.texto }}</p>
</div>
```

El post.texto puede ser de 5 caracteres o de 1000, cuando es de muchos caracteres se sale del div, y el texto continua haciendo la pagina enorme.
¿Como podría hacer para que se mantenga dentro del div y haga los linebreak para no salirse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que django tiene poco que ver aquí, la cuestión es arreglarlo con css, te dejo aquí un ejemplo a ver si te sirve:

https://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pTH6Y/

Comment: Tienes razon. Tuve que añadir un `word-wrap: break-word;` al css del div